# After program termination, return to the start of the main code or somewhere else

Tags: java, loops

I am brand new to programming in general, I'm currently studying programming in games, which one of the main things that have in games are loops, more specifically about those who after completing a certain objective, it returns to another part of the game, like if it was restarting all over again.
The question is, what type of looping should I use to do it? Take a look at this basic code so you can understand what I'm talking about.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner scan = new Scanner();
String x;
System.out.println("Hello, how's it going?");
x = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("Nice");
```

I want to do so **after writing on the scanner variable**, it **returns to the "Hello, how's it going"**, and **repeats this process** until I don't want to do it anymore, so I will know what to do at a more detailed situation.
Because the testing game I'm trying to make is just a basic loop of a simple code, just to start my programming journey.

Comment: Which loop do you think you should use? There really aren't that many to choose from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [do-while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop.

Here is an example of a loop that will only exit once the user inputs the string "exit":

```
do{
    System.out.println("Hello, how's it going?");
    x = scan.nextLine();
} while(!x.equals("exit"));
```